# Understand the math behind He-Initialization

Tags: variance, neural-networks

I tried to work the math of how Kaiming He et al could come up with their initialization method in this [paper](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDtaOg24XWAhXCH5QKHSNiChYQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1502.01852&usg=AFQjCNFFQpuBYK-XHBdypGxXmDRYZk3SNA).

Ignoring bias, we can get the variance of y as:

$$\mathrm{Var}[y] = n \mathrm{Var}[wx] $$

To get the Variance of [$wx$] I use this formula:

$$\mathrm{Var}[wx] = E[w^2]E[x^2] - [e[x]]^2[E[w]]^2$$

let $W$ has zero mean, so I left with:

$$\mathrm{Var}[wx] = E[w^2]E[x^2]$$

using the formula for variance, replace $E[w^2]$

$$\mathrm{Var}[wx] = \mathrm{Var}[w]E[x^2]$$

then substitute it back to the first equation

$$\mathrm{Var}[y] = n \mathrm{Var}[w]E[x^2] $$

from here, I am not sure how they could get the following:

$$\mathrm{Var}[y] = \frac12n \mathrm{Var}[w] \mathrm{Var}[y_{l-1}] $$

Can anyone explain to me?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y_{l-1}$ has zero mean and has a symmetrical distribution around zero.

\begin{align}\mathrm{Var}(y_{l-1})&=\mathbb{E}[y_{l-1}^2] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[y_{l-1}^2|y_{l-1} > 0]\mathrm{Pr}[y_{l-1} > 0] + \mathbb{E}[y_{l-1}^2|y_{l-1} < 0]\mathrm{Pr}[y_{l-1} < 0]\\
&= 2\mathbb{E}[y_{l-1}^2|y_{l-1} > 0]\mathrm{Pr}[y_{l-1} > 0] \tag{1}\end{align}
Since
$$x_l = \max(0,y_{l-1})$$

Hence $$x_l^2 = \begin{cases} y_{l-1}^2 & , y_{l-1} > 0 \\ 0 & , y_{l-1} \leq 0\end{cases}$$

and have $$\mathbb{E}[x_l^2]=\mathbb{E}[y_{l-1}^2|y_{l-1}> 0]\mathrm{Pr}[y_{l-1 }>0 ]=\frac12 \mathrm{Var}(y_{l-1})$$